# Reduce spacing between cells in Jupyter in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to reduce the spacing between cells in Jupyter in VSCode ? (see pic below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that this can be decreased by going to your VSCode settings search this `@tag:notebookLayout`. Here look for `Cell Toolbar Location` and edit the default value to `hidden`.

Or in your VScode JSON settings you can include this:

"notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
"default": "hidden"
}

Comment: nothing happened for me, still the same

Comment: Yeah, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `Notebook: Cell Toolbar Location` and `Notebook: Insert Toolbar Location` both set to value `hidden` adds up to reduce the spacing between cells.
I also reduced `Notebook › Output: Line Height` value from `default` to `14` to have a more compact view.